# Issues with saving PNG images to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

I have trouble storing **.png** images with this script. It stores **.jpeg** images, but not successfully storing **.png**. Problem is that with **.png** only half of the picture is stored. The image field in the database is of type blob.

When testing on my local xampp installation it stores lets say 90% of the picture, but when I try it on a hostgator hosted domain it stores lets say 45% of the picture

Don't think it is about the images are larger than the image column in the database as I have stored larger **.jpeg** images...

```
    static function save($_FILES) {
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost",DBUSER,DBPASS) or die("<b>Error:</b><br>".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DBNAME,$link) or die("Cant select db"); 

$tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);



    $sql = "INSERT INTO image
  (type, image, size, name)
  VALUES ('" .  mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['type']) . "', '" . $data . "', '" . $_FILES['image']['size'] . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']) . "')";       

mysql_query($sql);          
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing actual images in a database table; it's generally better to save the image file in your server's filesystem, and a simply filepath in the database

Comment: for one thing, you're using `type` which by MySQL's standards, is a reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html - checking for errors on your query, would have signaled the syntax error. `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: `static function save($_FILES)` - *bizarro*

Comment: You're gonna need that Mocha Frapachino Fred

Comment: Sounds yummo to mio!  @DrewPierce

Comment: [no upvote on my comment....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900673/issues-with-saving-png-to-database-mysql#comment49840323_30900673) - *well, I'll be...* Edit: ah... yes. Got one. True though. It requires *special attention* ;-) edit #2: Ouhhh... 2 of 'em, *sweet!* - Keep 'em comin'

Comment: I don't know what problem you're trying to solve, but I'm pretty sure you've not come up with the best solution. This code looks wrong on many levels.

Comment: Since no one has said it yet, might want to use PDO or mysqli as mysql_* functions are not deprecated and unsafe

Comment: A `BLOB` column only stores 16KB of data by default. You probably want [`LONGBLOB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html), or as others have pointed out, not putting images in the database where they simply do not belong. There are a ton of advantages of storing them on disk, like how you can delegate delivery of these assets to a web server or that backing up is not complicated and your database isn't bloated with binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
```

to

```
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'rb');
```

or try to use

```
file_get_contents()
```

and check.